# Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket “/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432”? in Odoo

Tags: postgresql, odoo-8

After some time the Postgres database stopped working of my live server. I'm working on this server from last 8 months. Now suddenly it's stopped working.

when I try to enter the command, psql produces an error

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXeus.png)

I'm using odoo8.

Comment: I got the same error just yesterday. Check if your postgres is running, for some reason, postgres stop.

Comment: Thanks Rafael, I checked it's showing:
9.5 main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log.
Restarted many times, but still same problem

Comment: /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main check the permission over this folder, I am not totally sure but must be rwx for postgres user, when I got my error was because of that.

Comment: checked all files in mail have -rw-r--r-- permission

Comment: yes, but what permissions for  /main folder itself?

Comment: it's drwxr-xr-x

Comment: sorry man, I am running out of ideas, but for sure the problem is postgres is stoped, run "sudo service postgresql start" and check the error log in /var/log/postgresql

Comment: After some changes in pg_hba.conf and removing postmaster.pid file it's fixed my issue. But there is another problem occur, pg_hba.conf file is automatically changed. Can anyone know or face this type of error?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to make sure the `socket file` is located in `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`. To check that

```
$ cat /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

if result shows something, then the problem is anything else. But, if file is not there you need to check `/tmp` dir (specially for OSX `Homebrew` users)

```
$ cd /tmp
$ l

total 16
drwxrwxrwt  7 root   wheel   224B Mar 11 08:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root   wheel   192B Jan 23 18:35 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   wheel    65B Nov  7 22:59 .BBE72B41371180178E084EEAF106AED4F350939DB95D3516864A1CC62E7AE82F
srwxrwxrwx  1 shiva  wheel     0B Mar 11 08:03 .s.PGSQL.5432
-rw-------  1 shiva  wheel    57B Mar 11 08:03 .s.PGSQL.5432.lock
drwx------  3 shiva  wheel    96B Mar 10 17:11 com.apple.launchd.C1tUB2MvF8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   wheel    64B Mar 10 17:10 powerlog
```

Now, there are two ways you can solve the error

### Solution One

You can change the application configuration to see for sockets at `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`

#### For Rails Users

```
# config/database.yml

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  # port: 
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: utf8
  # min_messages: warning
  socket: /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

### Solution Two

You can create symlinks to the expected location

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/pgsql_socket
$ sudo ln /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/pgsql_socket/
```

Then the error should go.

Hope this helps.

---

**Note:** Your default socket directory may not be `/tmp`

Answer (score 0):

Did you update/upgrade your database?
Did you start a docker container that interfered with any of your data-store/socket file locations?

This probably doesn't fit your situation exactly, but maybe it will provide some insight:

Sometimes when you try

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
```

and the systemd status says it is started but you still get that error message when trying to connect, try this instead:

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster <version> <cluster> <action>
```

which in my case had been

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 13 main start
```