# error in connection to server on socket (odoo 16) on ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, odoo-16

[image]I recently installed Odoo 16 on Ubuntu and everything seemed to go smoothly. However, when I try to create a database by accessing http://localhost:8069, I'm seeing an error. Can you suggest some steps I can take to fix this issue?

After running the command "sudo service postgresql restart", I checked the log file to ensure that there were no issues. Surprisingly, there were no error messages.

Comment: This troubleshot-guide might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894053/is-the-server-running-locally-and-accepting-connections-on-unix-domain-socket

Comment: ...and check the parameters (db_host ....) in your file xxx.conf in your src/odoo/ directory

Answer (score 0):

Let's check the parameters (db_host ....) in your file xxx.conf in your src/odoo/ directory

...using these guides :

- https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/administration/install/deploy.html
- https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-odoo-16-on-ubuntu-22-04/
- https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-odoo-16-on-ubuntu-22-04/

```
db_host = localhost
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = mydbname
db_password = False
db_port = 5432
db_sslmode = prefer
db_template = template0
db_user = False
dbfilter =
```

Otherwise, this troubleshot-guide might help you too :  [Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket “/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432”? in Odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894053/is-the-server-running-locally-and-accepting-connections-on-unix-domain-socket)

Alternatively, you could make a brand new install using Yenthe's installation script for Odoo16:
https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript

Comment: thanks,the problem is solved when I uninstall PostgreSQL and reinstall it